# Connection refused error with AWS + Hashicorp Vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, hashicorp-vault

I have configured a Hashicorp Vault server on a EC2 instance. When trying to use postman to test transit secret engine API I keep getting a error connection refused on postman, I went full ape mode and opened all ports on the security group inbound rule and it didn't work, I attached an elastic IP to the instance and didnt work either, im just trying with a simple GET and I just keep getting the same connectionrefused error.

When I use cUrl on the ssh connected session i have no issues though. The specified hosted adress is 127.0.0.1:8200, in postman I replaced that localhost with the public adress of the instance that i obviously censored in the screencap, in the headers theres the token needed to access vault, for simplicity I was just using the root token.

[Postman screecap if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3NOu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Emilio Marchant

I have faced similar issue (not with postman, but with telnet), Let's try to understand problem here.

The issue is with 127.0.0.1 IP. This is loopback IP and When you (or your computer) call an IP address, you are usually trying to contact another computer on the internet. However, if you call the IP address 127.0.0.1 then you are communicating with the localhost – in principle, with your own computer.

Reference link : https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/localhost/

What you can try is below.

1. Start vault dev server with --dev-listen-address parameter.

Eg:

```
vault server -dev -dev-listen-address="123.456.789.1:8200"
```

in above command replace '123.456.789.1:8200' with '<your ec2 instance private IP : 8200'>

2. Next set VAULT_ADDR and VAULT_TOKEN parameter as below

```
export VAULT_ADDR='http://123.456.789.1:8200'
export VAULT_TOKEN='*****************'
```

Again replace 'http://123.456.789.1:8200' with 'http://[Your ec2 instance private IP]:8200'

For Vault_token : you should get a root token in console, when you start vault server , use that token

Now try to connect from postman or using curl command. It should work.

Reference question and solution :

[How to connect to remote hashicorp vault server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296390/how-to-connect-to-remote-hashicorp-vault-server)

Comment: Thanks! I cant upvote things yet but I would if I could. I'm sure your answer will help future vault users too!

Answer (score 0):

The notable thing here is that the response is "connection refused". This error means that the connection is getting established and it found that there are no processes running on that port. This error means that there is no issue with firewall. A firewall will cause the connection to either drop (reject) or timeout (ignore), but won't give "Econnrefused".

The most likely issue is that the vault server process is not bound to the correct network interface. There must be a configuration in hashicorp-vault to setup the IP on which to bind. Most servers, by default, bind only on loopback address which is accessible only from `127.0.0.1`. You need to bind it to "all" network interfaces by changing that to `0.0.0.0`. I am not aware of the specific configuration option of hashicorp vault, but there has to be something to this effect.

Possible security issue:
Note that some servers expect you to run it behind a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) so that you can setup SSL (https) and other authentication if needed. Applications like vault servers should not be publicly accessible on http without SSL.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I know theres that security issue, this is not for production, just testing and such. About the adress bind, in the creation process of the vault server it asks for a host adress, and it is specified as 127.0.0.1:8200 with tls disabled, again just for testing purposes. I have to add that im not sure if tls disabling or the server not having a reverse proxy as you say or bastion instance is part of the issue, Im totally newbie to Vault and AWS so Ive been learning in the dark to be honest.

Comment: Comment 2: Now i can fully use the transit API from the SSH session with no issues, but postman doesnt work at all

Comment: If you can change the host address to 0.0.0.0:8200 instead of 127.0.0.1:8200 in the configuration, then it will probably work. TLS shouldn't be the cause of this issue.