# How to connect to remote hashicorp vault server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, telnet, vault

Let me explain my use-case here,

I wanted to give a try to vault in my local, so I configured `VAULT_ADDR` as:

```
$ echo $VAULT_ADDR 
http://127.0.0.1:8200
```

then I started vault in dev mode (`vault server -dev`) and everything was ok, I was able to connect to the server.

Then I wrote a really simple config file:

```
$ cat vault.config 
backend "inmem" {}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}

disable_mlock = true
```

and I restarted the server with `vault server -config=vault.config`, This too worked fine.

Now I want to use vault server which is deployed in remote server (aws ec2 instance). I have changed content my config file to below

```
backend "inmem" {}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "123.456.789.1:8200" (aws ec2 public ip)
  tls_disable = 1
}

disable_mlock = true
```

now this is throwing error

```
Error checking seal status: Get "http://123.456.789.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp 123.456.789.1:8200: connect: connection refused'
```

when i am trying to check connectivity using telnet command, that too failed.

```
  telnet 123.456.789.1 8200
```

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I have opened 8200 port in security group of aws, and both instances are in same vpc. What I am missing here? Any help?

Comment: I was able to figure out answer for above question. This post helped me 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676084/is-it-possible-to-start-vault-dev-server-on-0-0-0-0-instead-of-127-0-0-1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out solution for above issue. Basically I executed below steps.

1. First I started vault server in above machine ( '123.456.XXX.X' ) by below command

```
vault server -dev -dev-listen-address="123.456.789.1:8200"
```

here 123.456.789.1 --> This is private IP of my ec2 instance, where my vault server is running.

2. Next, In my source machine (the one from which i am invoking vault server in 123.456.XXX.X ), I set below parameters

```
export VAULT_ADDR='http://123.456.789.1:8200'
export VAULT_TOKEN='*****************'
```

3. Now when I am trying to do telnet to 123.456.XXX.X server, it is working as expected

```
telnet 123.456.789.1 8200
```

output

```
Trying 123.456.789.1...
Connected to 123.456.789.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: where do you get your vault token from ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem
I was trying to reach my remote vault server this helps me https://stackoverflow.com/a/67218570/19887897

You just have to start your server like this

```bash
vault server -dev  -dev-listen-address="0.0.0.0:8200"
```